# How can i remove the horizontal line in my Table?

Tags: html, css

Any idea, How can i remove the line horizontal from the table?

css, html

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse">

            <tr>
                <th>Prepared By:</th>
                <th>Released By:</th>
                <th>Trucker's Acknowledgement</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">Driver : ______________                Helper: ______________ </font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><font size="1">Contact Nos. : ______________</font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

i want to remove only the horizontal line table[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't write **Global `th` or `td` CSS** it'll impact all `tables th/td`. Add custom class like `table-no-bottom-border` for the table and write **no bottom border** CSS for only this table. All mentioned updates are include in below **code snippet**. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.table-no-bottom-border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%; 
}

.table-no-bottom-border th,
.table-no-bottom-border td {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-no-bottom-border th:last-child,
.table-no-bottom-border td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-no-bottom-border" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
      <th>Prepared By:</th>
      <th>Released By:</th>
      <th>Trucker's Acknowledgement</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
      <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
      <td><font size="1">Driver : ______________                Helper: ______________ </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
      <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><font size="1">Contact Nos. : ______________</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: may i ask something? how can i add border-radius? i add border-radius from table-no-border but no effect?

Comment: .table-no-bottom-border { 
   border-radius: 5px; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%; 

}     i add border-radius. why not change?

Comment: `border-radius` will not work with `border-collapse`. Let me update the code snippet for you

Comment: your awesome dude tnx . much appreciated.

Comment: I just update the above code snippet with `border-radius`, i hope it'll help you out and thank you for the last comment. :)

Comment: Yes tnx dude. it mean to me

Comment: HI @hassan Siddiqui. are u there? my i ask a favor?

Comment: Sure, come on chat in morning.

Comment: I have trouble in my other table. i cant merge it as 1 table. they are separated. i want to have only 1 table. see my picture below.

Comment: If i remove colspan . the tables are separated . like Drop 1 to Routname only, same as Drop 2, drop 3 and drop 4. i want only inside 1 table.

Comment: they said. i go used <div> for merge the table as 1. but i dont know how. im not good in tables..

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the horizontal lines are the `border-bottom` css property. So set that to 0 and it would remove horizontal lines.

**Edit:**

Add a class to the table so that only this particular class's table will get affected.

Try this:

```css
.table-modify tr {
  border-bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table-modify" border="1" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse">

  <tr>
    <th>Prepared By:</th>
    <th>Released By:</th>
    <th>Trucker's Acknowledgement</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font size="1">Driver : ______________ Helper: ______________ </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <font size="1">Signature/Date</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font size="1">Signature/Date</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
      <font size="1">Contact Nos. : ______________</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi. but i have other tables. not only this, so it may effect the other tables right?

Comment: Yes it will affect, so add a class to it. So that only that particular's class's table will get affected. I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Ok updated the answer with the class. Add a class name to the table and then reference it in the CSS with the class name, which in this case, I called it `table-modify`

Comment: please don't automatically click on the *tidy* button when editing question like you did here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57373242/8620333. You completely change the meaning of his code. He's using inline-block element and space are very important and they explicitely removed. By clicking on *tidy* you put them back

Answer (score 0):

Just give border-top and border-bottom to none for a table td. It will remove the horizontal border from all td. And If you want to remove the horizontal line from the table header also, the just give border-bottom to none for a table th.

```
th {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Otherwise give CSS property in the table td only.

```css
 td {
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: none;
   }
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <th>Prepared By:</th>
                <th>Released By:</th>
                <th>Trucker's Acknowledgement</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">/*auto populated*/</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">Driver : ______________                Helper: ______________ </font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
                <td><font size="1">Signature/Date</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><font size="1">Contact Nos. : ______________</font></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) @Hassan Siddiqui here master.
[image]

Comment: .no-bottom-border{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width:100%;
 
}
.no-bottom-border td {
  border-top: none;
}

Comment: <table class="no-bottom-border">
<tr>
<td><b>Drop</b> : {{$value['sequence_id']}}</td>
<td><b>Route Code</b> : {{$value['route_no']}}</td>
<td><b>Route Name</b> : {{$route_name}}</td>
</tr>
<?php
$getVsr = \App\Modules\Entities\VSR\VSR::where('route_no',$value['route_no'])->get();    // dd($getVsr);?> <tr>  <td colspan="3"><table><tr>   <th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>ENV</th>
<th>VSR NO.</th>
      <th>BOX/BDL</th>
      <th>SEAL NO.</th>
      <th>PADLOCK NO.</th>
      <th>DEST-ATA</th>
      <th>DEST-ATD</th>
      <th>REMARKS</th>
      <th>RECEIVED BY/DATE</th>
     </tr>

Comment: @foreach($getVsr as $vsrVal)
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['env']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['seal_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['padlock_no']}}</td>
      <td>__________</td>
      <td>__________</td>
      <td>__________</td>
      <td>__________</td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>


               </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
    </table>